# Enable SSH without screen Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I try to enable SSH on my raspberryPi 4. I don't have screen and it's for that I created ssh file (without extansion) in D:boot. When I try to log in I get an 'Acces denied' response from ssh terminal. I try with pi id and raspberry password. I created/default new raspberry image (x64). when I take back my sd card to check, ssh file doesn't exist.

Have you any issue.

Comment: Try asking at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: Note that recent versions of Raspberry Pi OS may no longer have a default user and password; see [this blog post](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/) for details.

Answer (score 7):

I was running into the same problem, but in this case its not a problem about SSH itself.

The real problem is RaspberryPiOS removed the default User "pi" since the lastest version (April 4th, 2022). Means you get "access denied" because there is no User named "pi". (Release notes here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/release_notes.txt)

To create a user you have 3 options: (use 1 out of 3)

1. Plug in a display and keyboard on your RasPi and follow the steps on screen to create a User.
2. Use the Raspberry Pi Imager tool to create a new Image on your SD-card. Under advanced settings you can set a username.
3. Flash the Image again and beside creating a "ssh"-file you need to create a "userconf.txt", containing a single line of text, consisting of "username:encrypted-password".
   For example: (to get standard-user "pi" and password "raspberry" again.)
   "pi:$6$/4.VdYgDm7RJ0qM1$FwXCeQgDKkqrOU3RIRuDSKpauAbBvP11msq9X58c8Que2l1Dwq3vdJMgiZlQSbEXGaY5esVHGBNbCxKLVNqZW1"
   More information here: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/warning-latest-raspberry-pi-os-image-april-4th-2022/54778

Hope i could help, have a great day!

WhisperFromDarkness

Comment: WhisperFromDarkness, your name couldnt be more appropriate :D Option #3 was a life saver and worked like a charm.

Comment: This is a true lifesaver, thank you so much. I don't like at all the direction the Raspbian developers are heading to. Raspi Imager? I don't use WIndows. Next step is that you can't use dd and must install Rufus? It is the user's responsibility to disable the "pi" account. I don't need to be spoonfed. Jumping through hoops to get the ordinary done is the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Did you manage to solve this yet? You can solve this using the **Raspberry Pi Imager** application.

To begin, when referring to the fact you have no screen, I assume you mean you are running the raspberry pi 'headless', meaning controlling it through secure shell (SSH) over your local network.

If you have not already installed the raspberry pi imager application, this can be found on the [official raspberry pi website](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/). On this application, you must select the relevant SD Card and operating system, before pressing *CTRL+SHIFT+X*, which will take you to the advanced settings page. Here, select 'enable SSH', before entering your WIFI SSID and password.

Once you have completed these steps and re-entered the SD card into the raspberry pi, you may open the terminal and enter `'SSH pi@ipaddress'`, followed by the password you created during setup, or the default password, which I believe is simply 'pi'. You will now have access to the Pi through SSH. Enter the command

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and you may alter the configuration settings as you like. Here, you may wish to change the VNC settings, so that you can view your raspberry pi GUI through remote desktop SSH.

I hope this was relevant and solved your query.

Answer (score 1):

What is so maddening about this is that the latest Imager (at least the macOS version) pre-populates the user name in the advanced screen with "pi", which is no longer a valid user. After about 3 attempts, it dawned on me that I had to put in a different username and password to get SSH to work. They should definitely update the Imager with a blank username.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).